# NoClassDefFOundError on Android after Manifest changes

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

My Android App was working perfectly fine then I tried to reload it onto my device and I suddenly get this error:

```
05-21 11:03:13.217: W/dalvikvm(18699): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4133b930)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.rns.us.iepareporting.SwipeEnterResults
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at com.rns.us.iepareporting.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:21)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-21 11:03:13.227: E/AndroidRuntime(18699):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I had just made changes to my manifest file, but I only removed references to activities that I am no longer using in my app.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rns.us.iepareporting"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.rns.us.iepareporting.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.rns.us.iepareporting.SwipeEnterResults"
            android:label="@string/strSwipeView"
            android:parentActivityName="com.rns.us.iepareporting.MainActivity">            
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.rns.us.iepareporting.EnterDailyResults"
            android:label="@string/strDailyResultsWells14_15"
            android:parentActivityName="com.rns.us.iepareporting.MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.rns.us.iepareporting.ReviewResults"
            android:label="@string/strReview"
            android:parentActivityName="com.rns.us.iepareporting.EnterDailyResults">            
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: just clean and rebuild the project and check..

Comment: did you recently update your adt to ver 22

Comment: the package defined in the manifest and the one from your stacktrace are different. Try cleaning your project

Comment: Better: Could you please check that the package in the manifest file (com.rns.us.reporting) and the one defined in your activities (i.e directory structure) files are equals?

Comment: I believe I did the update to ver22 the other day. I also just updated the manifest in here as well in my project. Still having the issue. I've also cleaned the project a number of times.

Comment: I ended up finding the solution on another question after doing some additional digging.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in the activity you use to launch the SwipeEnterResults activity, there is a typo in your intent.

Try opening that file, and searching for "iepareporting". Remove the "iepa" when you find it. (ie. change it to "reporting")

If not, the typo is somewhere else. Try searching the entire project for "iepareporting".